# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'LayoutMode' of undefined

Tags: jquery, html, layout, jquery-isotope

HI i am making my project using Isotope.js where i have to show my tiles in the horizontal manner,
So i am following code

```
var winDow = $(window);
    // Needed variables
    var $container=$('.portfolio-box, .blog-box');
    var $filter=$('.filter');

    try{
        $container.imagesLoaded( function(){
            $container.show();
            $container.isotope({
                layoutMode: 'masonryHorizontal',
                masonryHorizontal: {
                    rowHeight: 50
                },

            });
        });
    } catch(err) {
    }
```

but unluckily it is not working , error on the console is

```
1.    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'LayoutMode' of undefined
2.    Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Help is appreciable must

Comment: masonryHorizontal: { rowHeight: 50 } should be masonry: { rowheight: 50 }

Not sure if it fixes it though. Could you post a codepen or jsfiddle with an example of what you're working with?

Comment: yes i change but it is not working @cowcowmoomoo

Comment: Can you post an example with markup?

Comment: Post your code to jsfiddle or codepen

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54036/discussion-between-jatt-net-and-cowcowmoomoo).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not including the isotope plugin on your page.

You need to include both `isotope.pkgd.min.js` and `masonry-horizontal.js`

---

This is grabbed from your site. If you uncomment that line, you should be good.

```
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.isotope.min.js"></script>-->
```

Comment: let me do plz, as now i have to add only  isotope.pkgd.min.js, right?

Comment: Yes. Add the plugin js to your html before the masonry-horizontal.js

Comment: plz see my site and link i send to you

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the same problem and found something. The jquery-isotope never sets `window.Isotope.LayoutMode`. That's why it is undefined.
If you don't use the jquery and just the regular one, you should not have this problem.

I fixed it by include the `layout-mode.js` right **after** `jquery.isotope.js`, and just **before** the `masonry-horizontal.js`